# Is it possible to change MTU value in android permanently

Tags: android, adb, mtu

I have a rooted device and using static IP address on my phone. I am trying to change the MTU value using this command:

```
adb shell su ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1440
```

but value reset back to default mtu(1500) when i reboot my phone. Is there any way permanently change the value so that custom value persist either phone reboot or WIFI service restart.

Comment: Even I want to know. Did you find the solution?